# Pandas: Compare between same columns for same Ids between 2 dataframes and create a new dataframe with the differences for each column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

Hello
I have 2 dataframes one old and one new. After comparing the 2 dataframes I want output generated with the column names for each id and the only changes in values as shown below.

I could merge the 2 dataframes and find the differences for each column separately like

```
a=df1.merge(df2, on='Ids')    
a[a['ColA_x'] != a['ColA_y']]
```

But I have 80 columns and I want to get the difference with column names and values as shown in the output. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please provide your dataframes as text, not as screenshots. We cannot copy screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack each dataframe to convert column names into row indexes. Concatenate the dataframes side by side:

```
combined = pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], axis=1)
```

Now, extract the rows with the values that do not match:

```
combined[combined[0] != combined[1]]
#           0   1
#Ids             
#123 ColA  AH  AB
#234 ColB  GO  MO
#456 ColA  GH  AB
#...
```

Comment: Thanks. It works if the Ids are always unique. If there are duplicate Ids present and I want to keep the duplicates, how can I make it work?

Comment: Then you should use row/line numbers instead of IDs, assuming that they match in both dataframes.